# How to check for non-zero values in 4D matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, zero, any

I am stuck with this simple matrix operation.
I have the 4D matrix called F, class double, with  size(F)= 10   345   345    14. (I am not quite sure if I should have converted to logical)
It contains 0s and 1s and it represents a mask after some operations to check neighbouring.
I need to see for each 'object' (first dimension, 1:10), if there are any non-zero values and create a logical array Con with size(Con)=10 that will have 1 if there are non-zero values, or 0 if all values are 0.
I tried many different approaches, I am not sure how many 'any' I should put and if I need to apply squeeze every time.
This is my code:

```
[m,n,o,p]=size(F);

for ob=1:m         %for each object
    A=F(ob,:,:,:);
    A=squeeze(A);
    if any(A(:))
       Con(ob)=1;
    else
       Con(ob)=0;
    end

end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Ziggy.

Comment: Don't you mean `[m,n,o,p]=size(F);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
Con = any(reshape(F,m,[]),2)
```

Comment: Thank you, Divakar! Nice and compact!

I was hoping I would get different results in this last step in my code..turns out I must have an error in earlier steps..

Comment: @ziggy Hmm, well can't help you there, can I? Let me know either way!

Comment: No worries, I will try to solve it and come back with a question again otherwise! Thanks again!